# Fetch array with in multiple field

Tags: php, mysql

```
| PID | CID | tel_numbers  |
|  1  |  1  | 1231231123  |    PID = auto increment (phone_id current table)
|  2  |  1  | 124312412   |    CID = id of contacts (contact_id from contact table)
|  3  |  2  | 43543545    |    tel_numbers  
|  4  |  2  | 12123123    |
|  5  |  3  | 23423423    |
|  6  |  4  | 22342342    |
```

I am new in php need help to fetch all data by CID in respective input fields to make editable but below code only display every first record of CID;

```
//PHP GET by id  

require_once('config.php');
$conn = connect();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addr_phone WHERE CID = $id ";
$query = $conn->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_array(); 
$conn->close();

//And display fields

DISPLAY FIELDS 
<div class=" input_fields_wrap row">
<span class="input-group-btn " id="sizing-addon1">
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" name="ephone[]" class="form-control phone"  value="<?=$result['tel_numbers']?>" placeholder="Phone Number">
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" name="ephone[]" class="form-control phone"  value="<?=$result['tel_numbers']?>" placeholder="Phone Number">
</span>
</div>
```

e.g if i select CID = "2"  so it should display both tel_numbers first in 1st input field and second in 2nd input field.

Above code display first record in both input fields and second one not showing but i want to display all tel_numbers by CID in each input field one by one.

i used while loop but required both input at the same time to display. if i have only one tel_number and want to add another tel_number number so i need both input fields.

Actually this form is designed for edit/ phone number if someone already added 1st  phone number and required to update/add another phone number . e,g  if cid= "3" which has only 1st tel_number  to display in input through while loop and i want to add cid= "3"  second tel_number so there must be input required .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop in the values to be placed sequentially.

```
<?php while($result = $query->fetch_array()){ ?>
<div class=" input_fields_wrap row">
<span class="input-group-btn " id="sizing-addon1">
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" name="ephone[]" class="form-control phone"  value="<?=$result['tel_numbers']?>" placeholder="Phone Number">
</span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes i did it but i need both field in static .Actually this form is designed for edit/ phone number if someone already added 1st  phone number and required to update/add another phone number . e,g  if cid= "3" which has only 1st tel_number  to display in input through while loop and i want to add cid= "3"  second tel_number so there must be input required .

simply through this form contact person can change tel number and also update if he/she got new number.

Comment: Ohh so you can add another `input` with an empty value too and then process on it further.